# select by month from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Friends. I am confused with the following queries.

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT strftime('%W', tm.txn_date) AS week, 
               sum(case when cm.master_id = 1 then (tm.amount - tm.pre_amount) else 0 end) AS Income, 
               sum(case when cm.master_id = 2 then (tm.pre_amount - tm.amount) else 0 end) AS Expense 
               FROM transmaster tm 
               INNER JOIN subcatmasters scm ON tm.scmaster_id = scm.id 
               INNER JOIN catmasters cm ON scm.catmaster_id = cm.id 
               WHERE strftime('%m', tm.txn_date) = '05' 
               GROUP BY week ORDER BY week DESC", null);
```

This one works perfectly but.

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT strftime('%W', tm.txn_date) AS week, 
               sum(case when cm.master_id = 1 then (tm.amount - tm.pre_amount) else 0 end) AS Income, 
               sum(case when cm.master_id = 2 then (tm.pre_amount - tm.amount) else 0 end) AS Expense 
               FROM transmaster tm 
               INNER JOIN subcatmasters scm ON tm.scmaster_id = scm.id 
               INNER JOIN catmasters cm ON scm.catmaster_id = cm.id 
               WHERE strftime('%m', tm.txn_date) = '"+05+"' 
               GROUP BY week ORDER BY week DESC", null);
```

This one didn't work. What is the problem friends.

I am just change `WHERE strftime('%m', tm.txn_date) = '05'` this line to `WHERE strftime('%m', tm.txn_date) = '"+05+"'` Why because I want to give the month number explicitly.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT strftime('%W', tm.txn_date) AS week, 
               sum(case when cm.master_id = 1 then (tm.amount - tm.pre_amount) else 0 end) AS Income, 
               sum(case when cm.master_id = 2 then (tm.pre_amount - tm.amount) else 0 end) AS Expense 
               FROM transmaster tm 
               INNER JOIN subcatmasters scm ON tm.scmaster_id = scm.id 
               INNER JOIN catmasters cm ON scm.catmaster_id = cm.id 
               WHERE strftime('%m', tm.txn_date) = '0"+5+"' 
               GROUP BY week ORDER BY week DESC", null);
```

What about ?

Comment: ah! My greatness. Thank you friend

Comment: You're welcome, but be carefull, for the months like : 10, 11 and 12, do not forget to not add the zero.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something cleaner and declare a variable for your month number:

```
String monthNumber = "05";
String request = "SELECT strftime('%W', tm.txn_date) AS week, " +
               "sum(case when cm.master_id = 1 then (tm.amount - tm.pre_amount) else 0 end) AS Income, " +
               "sum(case when cm.master_id = 2 then (tm.pre_amount - tm.amount) else 0 end) AS Expense " +
               "FROM transmaster tm " +
               "INNER JOIN subcatmasters scm ON tm.scmaster_id = scm.id " +
               "INNER JOIN catmasters cm ON scm.catmaster_id = cm.id " +
               "WHERE strftime('%m', tm.txn_date) = '" + monthNumber + "' " +
               "GROUP BY week ORDER BY week DESC";
c = db.rawQuery(request, null);
```